# Django - disallow NaN and infinity in FloatField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How can I make a `FloatField` in Django that does not allow saving NaN or Infinity values (while still allowing null values) - i.e. something along the lines of:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    rate = models.FloatField(null=True, nans=False) # ???
```

I am using Postgres as a backend. If a general solution does not exist, maybe there is a Postgres specific solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a constraint, you could also create a type or a domain, which can be used more than once

---

```
CREATE DOMAIN plain_float
        AS float /*NOT NULL*/ check( value <> 'nan'::float AND value > '-inf'::float AND value < '+inf'::float )
        ;

CREATE TABLE dummy
        ( id serial PRIMARY KEY
        , val plain_float
        );

\d dummy

INSERT INTO dummy(val) VALUES ( 0.5);   --Ok
INSERT INTO dummy(val) VALUES ('Nan');  --Fails
INSERT INTO dummy(val) VALUES ('-inf');  --Fails
INSERT INTO dummy(val) VALUES ('+inf');  --Fails

SELECT * FROM dummy;
```

---

(I Don't know how to pack this into your ORM)

---

RESULTS:

---

```
CREATE DOMAIN
CREATE TABLE
                             Table "tmp.dummy"
 Column |    Type     |                     Modifiers                      
--------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer     | not null default nextval('dummy_id_seq'::regclass)
 val    | plain_float | 
Indexes:
    "dummy_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  value for domain plain_float violates check constraint "plain_float_check"
ERROR:  value for domain plain_float violates check constraint "plain_float_check"
ERROR:  value for domain plain_float violates check constraint "plain_float_check"
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 | 0.5
(1 row)
```

Comment: It would be good to know if Django has a ready-made solution which creates the necessary constraints so that I don't have to create them by hand.

Comment: nice comment) no need to create huci buci here

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom field:

```
from django.db import models

class HandField(models.FloatField):

    description = "Custom FloatField"

    def check(self, **kwargs):
        errors = super().check(**kwargs)
        errors.extend(self._check_custom_format())
        return errors

def _check_custom_format(self):
    local_errors
    #Here you should check if the format is correct.
    #If something is not right, you should add an error object (from django.core.checks) to local_errors
    return local_errors
```

Error object:

```
checks.Error(
                    'Some error',
                    obj=self,
                    id='Some id',
                )
```

I haven't tried the coded, is based on IntegerField

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/checks/

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem partially - i.e., if I add the data to the DB not via Django it can still be invalid. How can impose the non-NaN constraint on the DB level?